# numpy arrays and list multiplication, finding the maximum and its index

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know that this question might seem repeated, but I tried to debug my code in several ways and still don't know what it is wrong. Below is my code.

```
def myfunc(LUT,LUT_Prob,test):
    x = []
    y = []
    z = []
    x.extend(hamming_distance(test, LUT[i]) for i in range (len(LUT)))
    y = [(len(LUT[0])) - j for j in x]
    z = [a*b for a,b in zip(y,LUT_prob)]
    MAP = max(z)
    closest_index = z.index(max(z))
    return x, y, LUT_Prob, z, MAP, closest_index
```

In another script:

```
Winner = []
for j in range (0,5):
    Winner.append(myfunc(LUT1,LUT_Prob1,test[j]))
print 'Winner = {}' .format(Winner)
```

The output is:

`Winner = [([2, 4, 2, 4], [8, 6, 8, 6], [array([ 0.4,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2])], [[array([ 3.2,  1.6,  1.6,  1.6])]], [array([ 3.2,  1.6,  1.6,  1.6])], 0), ([1, 3, 1, 3], [9, 7, 9, 7], [array([ 0.4,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2])], [[array([ 3.6,  1.8,  1.8,  1.8])]], [array([ 3.6,  1.8,  1.8,  1.8])], 0), ([3, 5, 5, 3], [7, 5, 5, 7], [array([ 0.4,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2])], [[array([ 2.8,  1.4,  1.4,  1.4])]], [array([ 2.8,  1.4,  1.4,  1.4])], 0), ([3, 5, 3, 5], [7, 5, 7, 5], [array([ 0.4,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2])], [[array([ 2.8,  1.4,  1.4,  1.4])]], [array([ 2.8,  1.4,  1.4,  1.4])], 0), ([3, 3, 3, 1], [7, 7, 7, 9], [array([ 0.4,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2])], [[array([ 2.8,  1.4,  1.4,  1.4])]], [array([ 2.8,  1.4,  1.4,  1.4])], 0)]`

Note: The output is the returned values `x, y, LUT_Prob, z, MAP, closest_index` with the same order and iterated 5 times.

The errors that I am getting:
1- `z` is not as expected, the expectation is multiply `y` and `LUT_Prob` element wise what I am getting is the results of multiplying the first element of `y` by `LUT_Prob`.
2- `MAP` should be only one value that is in this case "3.2" however there is an array instead.
3- `Max_index` in this case is correct, however, if the the "3.2" is anywhere else `Max_index` remains "0".

So, can somebody help?

Comment: Can you show examples to `LUT` and `test` ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar, `test=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]` which is an array that I read from a csv file and `LUT= array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]), array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]), array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]), array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])]`

Comment: From the above code, I do not see how `z` transformed into a `np.array` , are you sure this is the code being run? can you check if you have some other code that is getting run? Maybe a previous version of same function, how are you running this?

Comment: Me neither and I think that this is causing the problems I have. I run this code as a function taking `test`, `LUT`, and `LUT_Prob`. The only difference that this function is inside a `for` loop that loops around several `test` arrays and takes one `test` array at a time.

Comment: where does this function come from? Is this all inside one script? Or directly in interactive interpreter?

Comment: So, I use `def myfunc (LUT, LUT_Prob, test):` "the code above" `return MAP, closest_index` . and inside another python script I use `from functions import *` and then call `myfunc(LUT1,LUT_Prob1,test)`

Comment: Please copy-paste the actual tracebacks you're getting and [add them into your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32061444/edit).

Comment: @Evert Sorry, I don't know what do you mean by "actual tracebacks", do you mean the output I get?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your mention of "errors"; you don't have tracebacks, just different results from your expecations.

Comment: Are you always running the other python script from command line? or how else are you running that?

Comment: @Evert I added the output the way I get it.

Comment: @AnandSKumar I run the other python script from the command line using `python myfile.py`

Comment: I'm not sure what you achieve with the line `x.extend(hamming_distance(test, LUT[i]) for i in range (len(LUT)))`. It seems it's better written as `x = [hamming_distance(test, item) for item in LUT]`. If that's not your intention, I don't understand your script.

Comment: @Evert it is more or less the same and does the same job, I changed it to what you proposed and still the same output.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't saying it would solve your problem, but I just found the line confusing to comprehend at first sight.

Comment: What also helps in debugging is showing the intermediate `x`, `y` and `z` variables. And are `y` and `LUT_prob` indeed the same sized lists by the time they are input to the `zip` function?

Comment: @Evert Ok, I guess I found out the cause of the problem, that is `y` is a list of 5 elements while `LUT_prob` is a list of 1 element and that element is an array of 5 elements. So, maybe this is why the multiplication problem occurred.

Comment: If you turn `y` into an array it becomes as simple as `z = y * LUT_prob`. No `zip` function needed.